# Drools run time exception after integrating with my application

Tags: java, drools

When i executed the drool application without integration, it's working fine as expected. But after integrating with my application (added all the required jars as well)and trying to execute i'm facing the following error.

Please i need a quick solution. Thanks in advance

> org.drools.RuntimeDroolsException: Unable to load dialect
>   'org.drools.rule.builder.dialect.java.JavaDialectConfiguration:java:org.drools.rule.builder.dialect.java.JavaDialectConfiguration'
>     at
>   org.drools.compiler.PackageBuilderConfiguration.addDialect(PackageBuilderConfiguration.java:274)
>     at
>   org.drools.compiler.PackageBuilderConfiguration.buildDialectConfigurationMap(PackageBuilderConfiguration.java:259)
>     at
>   org.drools.compiler.PackageBuilderConfiguration.init(PackageBuilderConfiguration.java:176)
>     at
>   org.drools.compiler.PackageBuilderConfiguration.(PackageBuilderConfiguration.java:153)
>     at org.drools.compiler.PackageBuilder.(PackageBuilder.java:242)
>     at org.drools.compiler.PackageBuilder.(PackageBuilder.java:142)
>     at
>   org.drools.builder.impl.KnowledgeBuilderProviderImpl.newKnowledgeBuilder(KnowledgeBuilderProviderImpl.java:29)
>     at
>   org.drools.builder.KnowledgeBuilderFactory.newKnowledgeBuilder(KnowledgeBuilderFactory.java:29)
>     at com.sample.TestExample.readKnowledgeBase(TestExample.java:32)    at
>   com.sample.TestExample.ProductClassHolder(TestExample.java:49)    at
>   com.sample.TestExample.main(TestExample.java:26) Caused by:
>   java.lang.RuntimeException: The Eclipse JDT Core jar is not in the
>   classpath     at
>   org.drools.rule.builder.dialect.java.JavaDialectConfiguration.setCompiler(JavaDialectConfiguration.java:94)
>     at
>   org.drools.rule.builder.dialect.java.JavaDialectConfiguration.init(JavaDialectConfiguration.java:55)
>     at
>   org.drools.compiler.PackageBuilderConfiguration.addDialect(PackageBuilderConfiguration.java:270)
>     ... 10 more

Comment: Look at the stack trace: The Eclipse JDT Core jar is not in the classpath.

Comment: yes JDT core jar is missing, i added it then it's working

Comment: @kanni Where did you add the jar file ?

Comment: @laune Where did you add the jar file ?